# Angular : http.get() method in angular will not give updated response for second same request call for API

Tags: angular, rest

```
 return this.http.get(URL,{search : this.urlParams})
  .map((res : Response)=>res.json())
  .catch(this.handleEr**strong text**ror);
```

**It works fine for all other browsers. except for internet explorer browser 11. Please suggest me any solutions.  help will be appreciated. thanks**

the above chunk of code will be present in "service.ts". click on "xyz" button will give a call to this function and gives a response back. even if you call the same function again, will getting the same response (or updated response) again for same rest API request. we will not receive response again once we make call in internet explorer. why second call isn't hitting the rest api in ie browser?  any suggestions on how to achieve it. thankful for your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent IE11 caching GET call in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755782/prevent-ie11-caching-get-call-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`let currentDate=new Date().getTime();
this.urlParams.set('currentdate',`${currentDate}`);`
```

I added above code wherever I am calling the rest API