# Angular doesn't update model from json service

Tags: angular

Versions:
node : 10.7.0
npm : 6.1.0

**The Architecture:**
My page is a simple concept, it renders new photos that are placed in the assets folder, the information is added to a json file which is placed within the assets folder. I have a service that reads the json file then sends an Observable to the component which has the location of the image and some other fields.

**The Problem**
When I publish the site, all browsers render the contents from last publish and do not display the updated pictures or json file.

When I run local, I have no problem, all photos display.

Can someone please help shed a little light, thanks.

**Here is what the code looks like:**

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "name": "pic1",
    "location": "../../assets/photos/pic1.jpg",
    "date": "4/28/2018",
    "comments": "this is pic1"
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "name": "pic2",
    "location": "../../assets/photos/pic2.jpg",
    "date": "4/28/2018",
    "comments": "this is pic2"
  }
]
```

**The Service**

```
 getAllPhotos(){
   photoPath = '../../assets/photoInfo.json';
   return this.http.get(this.photoPath);
 }
```

**The Component**

```
  data : any;

  constructor(private _data: PhotoAlbumService,private zone : NgZone,  public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.data = new Array<IPhoto>();
  }
  getRecentPhotos(): void {
        this._data.getAllPhotos()
            .subscribe(recent => { 
                 this.zone.run(() => { // <== added
                     this.data = recent;
                 });
        });
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    let timer;
    this.getRecentPhotos();
    timer = timer(2000, 5000);
    timer.subscribe(() => this.getRecentPhotos());
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify the issue a bit please? What do you mean by *"the updated pictures"*? How are you updating them? It sounds like you're probably only updating the copy that's held in memory, so each time the server restarts your application, the changes are lost

Comment: so new pictures that are added to assets and the json file are not displayed on page.

Comment: And how are how adding the pictures to the assets directory? I don't believe you'll be able to do that with Angular

Comment: They go in manually

Comment: So on local host, new pictures are displayed. In production, it seems that pictures are cached and when new ones are added/removed the changes are not reflected.

Comment: I believe Angular needs to recompile each time assets are added

Comment: yes, a new build is always pushed

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache to see if the browser is caching the old JSON file?

Comment: So the concern is for other users, they should not have to clear their cache every time they visit a page.

Comment: A (somewhat hacky) way around it is to add a random querystring to end of the url, so it becomes `photoPath = '../../assets/photoInfo.json?now=' + Date.now();`, which should prevent the browser from caching

Answer (score 0):

It seems the GET request is cached. You can set Cache-Control option to no-cache in order to stop HTTP request from getting cached.

Check this thread for more details: [Prevent IE11 caching GET call in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755782/prevent-ie11-caching-get-call-in-angular-2)

Comment: So I have this at the top of the page:   
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

Comment: Have you checked request headers in developer tools? Does it set the cache-control header properly?  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers) suggests to set HTTP headers of the request and not rely on meta tags.