# Clear browser Cache after deploying Angular 7 application on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, browser-cache

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: `./app/component/stuff/component.html?v=${new Date().getTime()}`,
  styleUrls: [`./app/component/stuff/component.css?v=${new Date().getTime()}`]
})
```

Can I use like above in Angular 7?

I need to clear the browser cache. I am referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671383/14574686) answer and but this for angular 2.

**Application hosted on the IIS**

So far I have tried the below answers but no output.

1)[Cache busting after deploying Angular 8 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989172/cache-busting-after-deploying-angular-8-application)

2)[How to prevent Browser cache on Angular 2 site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647810/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-on-angular-2-site)

3)[Clear browser cache in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517060/clear-browser-cache-in-angular)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to do is making sure that the index.html is not cached (or for a very short time) See [How to disable caching of single page application HTML file served through IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26666450/1956072). All other resources are packaged by angular and cache busted by default.

Comment: How I can do index.html is not cached?