# Angular 13 app served on Nginx has to clear cache after deploy

Tags: angular, nginx, caching, deployment

We have an Angular 13 app served on Nginx. Usually, when we deploy new changes, we don't seem them until we do a hard refresh on the page, clearing the cache.

I've seen this issue in a few questions around, but none of the solutions worked so far:

- [Angular app has to clear cache after new deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment)
- [Cache busting after deploying Angular 8 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989172/cache-busting-after-deploying-angular-8-application)
- [Clear browser cache in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517060/clear-browser-cache-in-angular)

We are using the build command

```
ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=all
```

And `angular.json` is configured with

```
"outputHashing": "all",
```

in dev and production.

I've tried HTML meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

I've searched about more general issues and configurations about cache:

- [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)
- [Caching Tutorial](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)

Or could this be caused by a cache config in Nginx? I've looked at [A Guide to Caching with NGINX and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/), but I'm not very familiarised with Nginx.

Comment: do you see different hash between deployments?

Comment: Where do I see the hash? Is it [this](https://medium.com/@dao.houssene/angular-the-hash-trap-b2d415c2c241) hash that should be enabled?

Comment: the number in the filename is what I refer as hash, something like main-8765.js. If the file name is different, browser will pick it up automatically

Comment: Most of the filenames (including several main.number.js) remain the same, but after a new deploy there is indeed a new hashed main.number.js

Comment: the hash has to change for browsers to update, so make sure you get the new number first, for some more info, you could check this: https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/

Comment: Update: months ago we moved the app to host it in AWS Amplify, which initially solved the cache problem. But after a while the problem reappeared... It's strange that it's intermittent and only happens in master branch, not in dev branch which has same configurations and is also deployed in Amplify. Also, we've already updated the app to Angular 16