# Angular app hosted on AWS Amplify sometimes has to clear cache after deploy

Tags: angular, caching, deployment, aws-amplify

Angular 16 app is hosted on AWS Amplify. Sometimes, when accessing the app, a previous cached version is displayed, and users need to hard reload the page to clear the cache and get the latest app version. The issue didn't happen in the first few months using Amplify, then it started happening intermittently, which is intriguing...

We have 2 versions deployed: a dev version and a prod one. The issue seems to only happen in prod version. So maybe it could be something related to branch-specific production configuration.

The build specification `amplify.yml` is:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - if [ "${AWS_BRANCH}" = "master" ]; then npm run build -- --configuration production; fi
            - if [ "${AWS_BRANCH}" = "dev" ]; then npm run build; fi
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: dist/app-name
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: webapp
```

Repo is a monorepo, so we're using monorepo configuration with appRoot in `webapp` directory.

We had some CORS-related errors so we're using these custom headers in `customHttp.yml` (which solved CORS errors):

```
applications:
  - appRoot: webapp
    customHeaders:
      - pattern: '**'
        headers:
          - key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            value: '*'
          - key: Vary
            value: >-
              Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers,
              Access-Control-Request-Method
```

By the way, we had this cache problem before when app was hosted in NGINX, as described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565088/angular-13-app-served-on-nginx-has-to-clear-cache-after-deploy).

Comment: the browser will cache client-side.  Don't know if it helps you, but I update client and server-side version numbers and check them against each other.  If they don't match I force a refresh with location.reload();  (I hard-code version numbers in front-end/back-end code when pushing updates...)

Comment: but it doesn't clear the cache, does it? wouldn't the refresh just leave the page with same cached version? According to location.reload() [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), `forceGet` parameter can be used to bypass the cache, but it's only supported in Firefox

Comment: It works for me without using forceGet.  I'll post my code in case it's helpful.  I found a conversation on the feature here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1037721

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to force reload when front-end/back-end versions don't match.
(You just need to create an endpoint to get the back-end version):

```
export class NavMenuComponent {
  isExpanded = false;
  public version: string = "0";
  public frontEndVersion: string = "1.1.34";
  private baseURL = environment.baseURL;
  
  private getVersionURL = this.baseURL + '/WebAPI/GetVersion';
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("hasReloaded")) { 
    this.GetVersion()
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.version = result.version;
        if (this.frontEndVersion != this.version) {
          sessionStorage.setItem("hasReloaded", "true");          
          location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
  }

 GetVersion(): Observable<any> { 
   return this.http.get<string>(this.getVersionURL, {})
     .pipe(
       tap(_ => this.log('fetched version'))
     );
 }
```

Comment: I didn't try it yet, but I suppose it will work. But I'd like to need not deploy backend at each frontend deploy

Comment: I suppose you could just force a location.reload() to fire once per session.  (remove the version check)  Keep the cookie check/set in place.  You can probably set headers (meta tag in page's <header>) to tell the browser to never cache the page, but that's not ideal... the caching behavior is useful.