IIS Loading an Old Site Content?
I am uploading an updated angular website version to IIS. However when I load the Site in a browser the old version appears. When I stop the site, still the old version appears.
I want the new version of the website to appear? What am I doing wrong ?
I am not using Service Worker at this point since it was a code written with angular 9 we have just upgraded the version to angular 17

if it's a browser-caching issue there are various ways to deal with it.  I provided an answer here that would check for updates per session: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77752718/angular-app-hosted-on-aws-amplify-sometimes-has-to-clear-cache-after-deploy/77760291#77760291  You can also check load event's "persisted" property to see if cached version is loaded.  (fairly new to browsers)

You have to build the project with the outputhashing flag:
ng build --aot --output-hashing=all  // <-- aot flag is default from the angular 9

Or it's better to make change in build configuration block inside the angular.json file:
{
  "projects": {
    "yourProjectNameHere": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "all" // <-- other value is media and bundles
            },
            "development": { 
              "outputHashing": "all" // only if you want to make it same in development  
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

disable Cache from index.html(you can use service worker cache instead) already answered
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">

Or make it change in iis configuration answered befor
trick: if you made this change after your files already deployed, try to reset iis pool too.

This may only resolve the problem partially. Because if the index.html (which never gets a hashed part in their name, even with outputHashing: all) is cached in the browser, it will still load (or at least try to load) the old js/css/... files

Disable HTTP cache control headers from index.html and use service worker api chace instead.

Your problem is caching the index.html. When you use CloudFront, there is an option to purge the cache which would force new requests to fetch the new index.html and thus fetch the new resources with it.
It looks like you are using some kind of custom setup. You need to discover how to reset the cache for your specific setup. Or, there is another option which is configure your server to send headers with index.html that it should be never cached. This should fix your problem.

You can try this :

You can try resetting IIS from an elevated command prompt by running
the command iisreset This will restart IIS and all hosted
applications.


CMD ===>
C:\Users\PC-Name>iisreset


Another option is to recycle the application pool associated with
your application. This can be done from the IIS Manager by selecting
your application pool and clicking Recycle in the Actions pane.
You can also try disabling all caching. In IIS Manager, navigate to the website or application where the cache needs to be cleared, double-click on the Output Caching feature, click on Edit Feature Settings in the Actions pane on the right, check the box that says Prevent all caching, and click on Apply to save the changes.

If none of the above methods work, you can manually delete the files in the following locations

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

