# Angular index.html no-cache?

Tags: angular, caching

index.html comes with cache
but it will be better for me if it is constantly reloaded,
I don't want to have cache. how can I do that

Thank you!

Comment: It can help to set your server environment to not cache your index.html file. I had to do that when setting up a PWA using Firebase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable caching with HttpClient get in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232382/how-to-disable-caching-with-httpclient-get-in-angular-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer,
Using meta HTML tags, Disable browser caching

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
```

`<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">`

Comment: <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you add these META tags onto your answer, not as a comment?