# Cache busting on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular application and very often after deployment I get complaints from end users that they are unable to see the new features (they still have to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd> before the changes reflect).

Do I need to incorporate cache busting? After a bit of Googling, I saw the following command:

```sh
ng build --output-hashing=all
```

I tried using it in my deployment pipeline and it was able to solve some of the issues but not all. there are some changes that I still need to do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd> for.

How do I make sure my application is updated for my end users without requiring them to clear their own cache?

```json
{
    "name": "portfolio",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prod-build-dev-old": "ng build --prod --configuration=dev --build-optimizer",
    "prod-build-dev": "ng build --prod --configuration=dev --build-optimizer --aot --output-hashing=all",
    "prod-build-staging": "ng build --prod --configuration=staging --build-optimizer"
},
```

Comment: Try : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233187/5980993

Comment: Also add your build configurations.

Comment: why do I need to disable caching ?

Comment: @AkshayAmar see: https://medium.com/acute-angular/angular-rookie-mistakes-how-to-cache-bust-an-angular-2-application-in-production-c4e4d1c48514

Comment: Coz that's why your clients don't have their apps updated = browser's cache, that's why they'd to ctrl + f5 => clean the cache

Comment: @SeleM , what do you mean ? so do you mean the issue is with the client ?

Comment: @AkshayAmar, it's a browser's cache behavior, that's why they have to do ctrl + f5 to get the updates.. if you want to avoid that.. you should tell the browser : "yo ! I don't want a you to cache my app" , Now, how to do it ? = by disabling the cache in your app's index.html + http headers as it's described in the links I sent.

Comment: @SeleM , do you have some example implementation that I can follow ? just in a small angular project. Thanks. I will pay if you can help me.

Comment: @AkshayAmar answered !

Comment: @AkshayAmar Could you please upvote the answer :) unless you'll give a donation for the help (as it was suggested by you in the upper comments :'D ) Thanks in advance !

Comment: I already done , upvoting Sir

Comment: it says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @AkshayAmar never mind

Comment: @AkshayAmar did you find a solution for the issue please comment if u did

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's a browser's cache issue. Although Angular includes cache busting by default, it requires you to manually turn off caching on index.html in order to give it a chance to run.

What I suggest is to add these three lines in your `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...

    <!--  Add the 3 following lines -->

    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">

    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Once these updates got deployed, your clients wont have to [`ctrl + f5`](https://www.debugbar.com/what-does-ctrl-f5-do/) after every deployment to get the new features.

For more informations about browser cache control, please check : [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) in MDN.

Comment: here https://imgur.com/a/c8IROf0 ?

Comment: @AkshayAmar after line 7 would be cleaner

Comment: can you explain to me SIr what this 3 lines actually do ?

Comment: @AkshayAmar TDLR, to prevent your browser from caching, in fact some of the options could be deprecated in latest versions, but it's better to keep them, you don't know which versions are used by your clients.. for more details, you can take for example : `no-store` , copy it and search for it in [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) with `cntrl + f` & you'll have detailed answers, and so on..

Comment: what is the downside of this solution ?

Comment: does this slow my app ?

Comment: Sir , where can I pay you what platform ?. I just have one last question , by adding the  meta and cache control you have said , I think it will slow my app since my app or browser would no longer do caching. Am I right ?

Comment: @AkshayAmar, Disabling cache -generally- hurts performance. It may make CDNs and ISP proxies (e.g. commonly used by mobile operators) ineffective. It doesn't hurt first load by a new user, but then subsequent navigation may be slower. And, yet.. slowness depends on how much resources you download.

Comment: @O'Rooney the court is yours to make a less terrible suggestion ^^
waiting for your answer + please, mention those much bigger problems

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong. I will delete my comment.

Comment: The missing part (which I added to your answer) is that Angular will do good caching and cache busting on changes, but for that to happen the index.html must not be cached.