# Disable or empty http cache in Angular2

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My application has a delete registration function, where I have to send a request to the server to remove my user and of course I have to delete all local data from the device. Request and storage clear done correctly but after registering again with the same user the data from the previous session still showed up on the pages.

This looks like it is caused by the http service cache, and if I call exitApp() after deleting the registration, it is working correctly not displaying data from the previous reg. However, exitApp doesn't seem to work on iOS.

So this is a 2in1 question, sorry.

**So How can I tell the http service that every earlier cached requests should now be deleted?
Or how can I tell the app on iOS to exit completely?**

Comment: Are you sure this is the  cache from http and not ionic pages that are cached ? To verify, use the chrome inspector on network tabs and verify that the request to your server is done.

Comment: @e666 You may be right because on the network tab there's no data coming back from the server. But I do clear the lists the pages working from locally on ionViewDidEnter. How can I clear page cache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to prevent Angular2 http request caching in internet explorer (IE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500804/proper-way-to-prevent-angular2-http-request-caching-in-internet-explorer-ie)

Comment: Can you provide some interesting part of your code ? Like how you get your data ?

Comment: Please check if that information is not being stored in any property from any service in your app (and thus, staying in memory)... since providers are singleton, the same instance will be use in the entire app. That would explain why it's deleted when you close the app.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method `setRoot` to clear DOM cache when you navigate to login screen.

Example :

```
deleteAccount() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
}
```

According to Ionic documentation :

> By default, pages are cached and left in the DOM if they are navigated away from but still in the navigation stack (the exiting page on a push() for example). They are destroyed when removed from the navigation stack (on pop() or setRoot()).

See here for more details : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: I'm using setRoot already, so my problem must be something else.